# Use EV $HOME in Logstash file input plug?

Tags: file, elasticsearch, input, logstash

The thing is, I am writing the config file for Logstash with file input plugin. The purpose is to setup a accommodated .conf file so that everybody can use it. Thus I will use environment variable `$HOME` to get the home directory of user, because the log path is related to that. However, when I am trying to do that,  for example:

```
"path" => "${HOME}/file.log"
```

I found Logstash only accepts absolute path, like "**/home/usr/file.log**".
Anything like **../logs** or .**/logs** all did not work.

So I am wondering, is there any other method I can do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not within the scope of logstash configuration.

> Paths must be absolute and cannot be relative.

Source: [`file` input documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-path)

---

With enough determination the answer is never, *truly*, no. You could use some tool, a script or program, maybe a templating language, to edit your logstash config file.

Comment: Are you sure writing a script to edit the config file will work? That's what I am trying to do, but I am not quite sure if it is the right way. Sorry, new to logstash

Comment: I don't know the specifics of your use case, but that how I would do it, which doesn't mean its the *right* way, just *a* way

Comment: I will try that. Thank you so much